# Cookie reads old data sometimes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, jquery-cookie

I want to make my sidemenu remember the last opened menu group on pagereload.  So I decided to make use of cookies for that.  The code is almost working fine, but shows some weird response at times.  The following is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastopen = $.cookie('activeAccordion');
    alert(lastopen); //But this takes old values sometimes,which means cookie is not getting updated
    if (lastopen != null) {
        //show the last opened group
        $("#" + lastopen).collapse("show");
    }
});

//function to save and update cookie on clicking the links in each group.
$('.accordion-body').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var active = $(this).attr('id');
        $.cookie('activeAccordion', active)
        alert($.cookie('activeAccordion', active)); //this alert works fine
    });
});
```

I think the cookie is reading some old data at times.  How do I update the cookie properly?  How to fix this issue?  Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Please note that I am setting this code in my layout file, which means this is applicable for a multiple number of pages/urls.

Comment: Your `$('.accordion-body').each(...` should be inside the `$(document).ready` block.

Comment: But that change didn't solve the problm.

Comment: I know. I was just advising you, that's why I didn't post it as an answer ;)